# Prediction.io - pio train fails with exception

Tags: prediction

just getting started with Prediction.IO - Getting an exception when performing pio train. I'm using the universal recommender template.

Pio status, and pio-start-all working fine, reporting no errors

Seems " nor Elasticsearch client found" - but curl localhost fine on port 9200.

Does anybody has a clue on what the error message given is referring to?

```
>     [INFO] [URModel] Ready to pass date fields names to closure Some(List(, , ))
>     [INFO] [URModel] Converting PropertyMap into Elasticsearch style rdd
>     [Stage 41:=============================>                            (2 + 2) / 4][INFO] [URModel] Grouping all correlators into doc +
> fields for writing to index
>     [INFO] [URModel] Finding non-empty RDDs from a list of 2 correlators and 1 properties
>     [INFO] [URModel] New data to index, performing a hot swap of the index.
>     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Elasticsearch client configuration detected, check your pio-env.sh
> forproper configuration settings
>             at dk.bilzonen.esClient$.client$lzycompute(esClient.scala:58)
>             at dk.bilzonen.esClient$.client(esClient.scala:55)
>             at dk.bilzonen.esClient$.hotSwap(esClient.scala:169)
>             at dk.bilzonen.URModel.save(URModel.scala:147)
>             at dk.bilzonen.URModel.save(URModel.scala:38)
>             at io.prediction.controller.P2LAlgorithm.makePersistentModel(P2LAlgorithm.scala:111)
>             at io.prediction.controller.Engine$$anonfun$makeSerializableModels$2.apply(Engine.scala:294)
>             at io.prediction.controller.Engine$$anonfun$makeSerializableModels$2.apply(Engine.scala:293)
>             at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>             at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>             at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
>             at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
>             at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
>             at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
>             at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>             at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
>             at io.prediction.controller.Engine.makeSerializableModels(Engine.scala:293)
>             at io.prediction.controller.Engine.train(Engine.scala:185)
>             at io.prediction.workflow.CoreWorkflow$.runTrain(CoreWorkflow.scala:65)
>             at io.prediction.workflow.CreateWorkflow$.main(CreateWorkflow.scala:247)
>             at io.prediction.workflow.CreateWorkflow.main(CreateWorkflow.scala)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>             at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>             at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
>             at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
>             at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
>             at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
>             at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Answer (score 0):

The default configuration for `PredictionIO` (in `pio-env.sh` in your `PredictionIO` `/conf` directory) has `ElasticSearch` running on `port 9300`. If you update it to `9200` there does your training step succeed?